# 6DOF Kinematics moveo

Tags: robotic-arm, arduino, kinematics, c

I asked on stackoverflow for the DH-Parameter for my robotic arm (moveo bcn3d).
I also copied the arduino code of Skyentific (YouTuber). Modified it to match my settings but i still does not work. Can someone please help me??? I am getting depressed if this keeps going like that.

In the home position, all joints have angle 0.
If I tell the forward kinematic that I want the 3rd joint and the 5th joint rotated 90 degrees, the values should be: (224, 0, 280) {x, y, z} should come out + some euler angles (can be ignored for now).
But I don't understand why these values come out, because the r and d values of the DH matrix are correct(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67159164/denavit-hartenberg-6dof-moveo-inverse-kinematic-robot-arm?noredirect=1#comment118726837_67159164)
Output of the Arduino:\

inverse:
0.00
0.00
-0.00
-180.00
180.00
-180.00

forward:
-224.00
0.00
280.00
45.00
180.00
45.00

In this example you can see that the inverse kinematic calculates three times 180 although the arm is already in the home position.
Also you can see that the forward kinematics calculates a negative number for the x axis and strange rotations for joints 4, 5 and 6.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

The DH-Parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67159164/denavit-hartenberg-6dof-moveo-inverse-kinematic-robot-arm?noredirect=1#comment118726837_67159164

His github:https://github.com/SkyentificGit/SmallRobotArm 
The YT-video:https://youtu.be/Sgsn2CM3bjY

You can ignore the Pins and just focus on the inverse and forward kinematics

```
/*
Simple script to move my tiny 6dof robotic arm
*/
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

//driver for the axis 1
#define PUL1_PIN 39
#define DIR1_PIN 37
//driver for the axis 2
#define PUL2_PIN 43
#define DIR2_PIN 41
//driver for the axis 3
#define PUL3_PIN 47
#define DIR3_PIN 45
//driver for the axis 4
#define PUL4_PIN 46
#define DIR4_PIN 48
//driver for the axis 5
#define PUL5_PIN A6
#define DIR5_PIN A7
//driver for the axis 6
#define PUL6_PIN A0
#define DIR6_PIN A1

//enable pin for the axis 3, 2 and 1
#define EN321_PIN 32
#define EN4_PIN A8
#define EN5_PIN A2
#define EN6_PIN 38

double curPos1 = 0.0;
double curPos2 = 0.0;
double curPos3 = 0.0;
double curPos4 = 0.0;
double curPos5 = 0.0;
double curPos6 = 0.0;

boolean PULstat1 = 0;
boolean PULstat2 = 0;
boolean PULstat3 = 0;
boolean PULstat4 = 0;
boolean PULstat5 = 0;
boolean PULstat6 = 0;

//robot geometry
const double dl1 = 360.0/200.0/32.0;
const double dl2 = 360.0/200.0/32.0;
const double dl3 = 360.0/200.0/32.0;
const double dl4 = 360.0/200.0/32.0;
const double dl5 = 360.0/200.0/32.0;
const double dl6 = 360.0/200.0/32.0;
const double r1 = 0.0;
const double r2 = 223.0;
const double r3 = 0.0;
const double d1 = 232.0;
const double d3 = 0.0;
const double d4 = 224.0;
const double d6 = 175.0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(PUL1_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DIR1_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PUL2_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DIR2_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PUL3_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DIR3_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PUL4_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DIR4_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PUL5_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DIR5_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PUL6_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DIR6_PIN, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(EN321_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EN4_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EN5_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EN6_PIN, OUTPUT);
  
  digitalWrite(PUL1_PIN, LOW); // gear ratio = 96/20 = 4.8
  digitalWrite(DIR1_PIN, LOW); //LOW = negative direction
  
  digitalWrite(PUL2_PIN, LOW); // gear ratio = 4
  digitalWrite(DIR2_PIN, LOW); //LOW = positive direction
  
  digitalWrite(PUL3_PIN, LOW); // gear ratio = 5
  digitalWrite(DIR3_PIN, LOW); //LOW = negative direction
  
  digitalWrite(PUL4_PIN, LOW); // gear ratio = 56/20 = 2.8
  digitalWrite(DIR4_PIN, LOW); //LOW = positive direction
  
  digitalWrite(PUL5_PIN, LOW); // gear ratio = 42/20 = 2.1
  digitalWrite(DIR5_PIN, LOW); //LOW = positive direction
  
  digitalWrite(PUL6_PIN, LOW); // gear ratio = 1
  digitalWrite(DIR6_PIN, LOW); //LOW = positive direction

  // all joints disabled!
  digitalWrite(EN32A1_PIN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(EN4_PIN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(EN5_PIN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(EN6_PIN, HIGH); 
}

void loop()
{
  // enable all joints
  delay(5000);
  Serial.println("gogo");
  digitalWrite(EN321_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(EN4_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(EN5_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(EN6_PIN, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  //--------------------------------------------------------GoGoGo-------------------
  curPos1=0.0;
  curPos2=0.0;
  curPos3=0.0;
  curPos4=0.0;
  curPos5=0.0;
  curPos6=0.0;

  //float Xhome[6]={0.0, 0.0, 854.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
  float Xhome[6]={224.0, 0.0, 280.0, 0.0, 180.0, 0.0};
  float Yhome[6]={0.0, 0.0, -90.0, 0.0, -90.0, 0.0};
  
  float X1[6]={164.5, 0.0, 141.0, 90.0, 180.0, -90.0};
  float X11[6]={164.5+14.7, 35.4, 141.0, 90.0, 180.0, -90.0};
  float X12[6]={164.5+50.0, 50.0, 141.0, 90.0, 180.0, -90.0};
  float X13[6]={164.5+85.3, 35.4, 141.0, 90.0, 180.0, -90.0};
  float X14[6]={164.5+100.0, 0.0, 141.0, 90.0, 180.0, -90.0};
  float X15[6]={164.5+85.3, -35.4, 141.0, 90.0, 180.0, -90.0};
  float X16[6]={164.5+50.0, -50.0, 141.0, 90.0, 180.0, -90.0};
  float X17[6]={164.5+14.7, -35.4, 141.0, 90.0, 180.0, -90.0};

  float X18[6]={164.5+50.0, 0.0, 141.0, 90.0, 180.0, -90.0};
  
  float X2[6]={264.5, 0.0, 141.0, 0.0, 90.0, 0.0};
  float X3[6]={164.5, 100.0, 141.0, 90.0, 90.0, 0.0};
  float X4[6]={164.5, -100.0, 141.0, 90.0, -90.0, 0.0};
  
  float Jhome[6], J1[6], J11[6], J12[6], J13[6], J14[6], J15[6], J16[6], J17[6], J18[6], J2[6], J3[6], J4[6];
  float Fhome[6];
  InverseK(Xhome, Jhome);
  ForwardK(Yhome, Fhome);
  Serial.println("inverse:");
  Serial.println(Jhome[0]);
  Serial.println(Jhome[1]);
  Serial.println(Jhome[2]);
  Serial.println(Jhome[3]);
  Serial.println(Jhome[4]);
  Serial.println(Jhome[5]);
  Serial.println("------");
  Serial.println("forward:");
  Serial.println(Fhome[0]);
  Serial.println(Fhome[1]);
  Serial.println(Fhome[2]);
  Serial.println(Fhome[3]);
  Serial.println(Fhome[4]);
  Serial.println(Fhome[5]);
  Serial.println("------");
  InverseK(X1, J1);
  InverseK(X11, J11);
  InverseK(X12, J12);
  InverseK(X13, J13);
  InverseK(X14, J14);
  InverseK(X15, J15);
  InverseK(X16, J16);
  InverseK(X17, J17);
  InverseK(X18, J18);
  InverseK(X2, J2);
  InverseK(X3, J3);
  InverseK(X4, J4);

  goStrightLine(Jhome, J1, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.0, 0.0);

  float velG=0.25e-4;
  goStrightLine(J1, J11, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.0, 0.5*velG);
  goStrightLine(J11, J12, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.5*velG, 0.5*velG);
  goStrightLine(J12, J13, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.5*velG, 0.5*velG);
  goStrightLine(J13, J14, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.5*velG, 0.5*velG);
  goStrightLine(J14, J15, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.5*velG, 0.5*velG);
  goStrightLine(J15, J16, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.5*velG, 0.5*velG);
  goStrightLine(J16, J17, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.5*velG, 0.5*velG);
  goStrightLine(J17, J1, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.5*velG, 0.0);

  goStrightLine(J1, J18, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.0, 0.8*velG);
  goStrightLine(J18, J14, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.8*velG, 0.0);
  goStrightLine(J14, J1, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.0, 0.0);
  
  goStrightLine(J1, J2, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.0, 0.0);
  goStrightLine(J2, J1, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.0, 0.0);

  goStrightLine(J1, J3, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.0, 0.0);
  goStrightLine(J3, J1, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.0, 0.0);

  goStrightLine(J1, J4, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.0, 0.0);
  goStrightLine(J4, J1, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.0, 0.0);
  
  goStrightLine(J1, Jhome, 0.25e-4, 0.75e-10, 0.0, 0.0);
  //--------------------------------------------------------GoGoGoBack---------------
}


void goStrightLine(float* xfi, float* xff, float vel0, float acc0, float velini, float velfin){
  //
  float lmax = max(abs(xff[0]-xfi[0]),abs(xff[1]-xfi[1]));
  lmax = max(lmax,abs(xff[2]-xfi[2]));
  lmax = max(lmax,abs(xff[3]-xfi[3]));
  lmax = max(lmax,abs(xff[4]-xfi[4]));
  lmax = max(lmax,abs(xff[5]-xfi[5]));
  unsigned long preMil = micros();
  double l = 0.0;
  vel0 = min(vel0,sqrt(lmax*acc0+0.5*velini*velini+0.5*velfin*velfin));
  unsigned long curMil = micros();
  unsigned long t = 0;
  double tap = vel0/acc0-velini/acc0;
  double lap = velini*tap+acc0*tap*tap/2.0;
  double lcsp = lmax-(vel0*vel0/2.0/acc0-velfin*velfin/2.0/acc0);
  double tcsp = (lcsp-lap)/vel0+tap;
  double tfin = vel0/acc0-velfin/acc0+tcsp;
  while (curMil-preMil<=tfin){
    t = curMil-preMil;
    //acceleration phase
    if (t<=tap) {
      l = velini*t+acc0*t*t/2.0;
    }
    //contant maximum speed phase
    if (t>tap && t<=tcsp) {
      l = lap+vel0*(t-tap);
    }
    //deceleration phase
    if (t>tcsp) {
      l = lcsp+vel0*(t-tcsp)-acc0*(t-tcsp)*(t-tcsp)/2.0;
    }
  
    //trajectory x and y as a function of l
    float Xx[6];
    Xx[0]=xfi[0]+(xff[0]-xfi[0])/lmax*l;
    Xx[1]=xfi[1]+(xff[1]-xfi[1])/lmax*l;
    Xx[2]=xfi[2]+(xff[2]-xfi[2])/lmax*l;
    Xx[3]=xfi[3]+(xff[3]-xfi[3])/lmax*l;
    Xx[4]=xfi[4]+(xff[4]-xfi[4])/lmax*l;
    Xx[5]=xfi[5]+(xff[5]-xfi[5])/lmax*l;
    
    goTrajectory(Xx);
    curMil = micros();
  }
}

void goTrajectory(float* Jf){
  
  //execution
  int delF=2;
  // joint #1
  if (Jf[0]-curPos1>0.0) { // positive direction of rotation
    digitalWrite(DIR1_PIN, HIGH);
    while (Jf[0]-curPos1>dl1/2.0) {
      if (PULstat1 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(PUL1_PIN, HIGH);
        PULstat1 = 1;
      } else {
        digitalWrite(PUL1_PIN, LOW);
        PULstat1 = 0;
      }
      //curPos1 = Jf[0];
      curPos1 = curPos1 + dl1/2.0;
      if (Jf[0]-curPos1>dl1/2.0) {
        delayMicroseconds(delF);
      }
    }
  } else {
    digitalWrite(DIR1_PIN, LOW);
    while (-Jf[0]+curPos1>dl1/2.0) {
      if (PULstat1 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(PUL1_PIN, HIGH);
        PULstat1 = 1;
      } else {
        digitalWrite(PUL1_PIN, LOW);
        PULstat1 = 0;
      }
      //curPos1 = Jf[0];
      curPos1 = curPos1 - dl1/2.0;
      if (-Jf[0]+curPos1>dl1/2.0) {
        delayMicroseconds(delF);
      }
    }
  }
  // joint #2
  if (Jf[1]-curPos2>0.0) { // positive direction of rotation
    digitalWrite(DIR2_PIN, HIGH);
    while (Jf[1]-curPos2>dl2/2.0) {
      if (PULstat2 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(PUL2_PIN, HIGH);
        PULstat2 = 1;
      } else {
        digitalWrite(PUL2_PIN, LOW);
        PULstat2 = 0;
      }
      //curPos2 = Jf[1];
      curPos2 = curPos2 + dl2/2.0;
      if (Jf[1]-curPos2>dl2/2.0) {
        delayMicroseconds(delF);
      }
    }
  } else {
    digitalWrite(DIR2_PIN, LOW);
    while (-Jf[1]+curPos2>dl2/2.0) {
      if (PULstat2 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(PUL2_PIN, HIGH);
        PULstat2 = 1;
      } else {
        digitalWrite(PUL2_PIN, LOW);
        PULstat2 = 0;
      }
      //curPos2 = Jf[1];
      curPos2 = curPos2 - dl2/2.0;
      if (-Jf[1]+curPos2>dl2/2.0) {
        delayMicroseconds(delF);
      }
    }
  }
  // joint #3
  if (Jf[2]-curPos3>0.0) { // positive direction of rotation
    digitalWrite(DIR3_PIN, LOW);
    while (Jf[2]-curPos3>dl3/2.0) {
      if (PULstat3 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(PUL3_PIN, HIGH);
        PULstat3 = 1;
      } else {
        digitalWrite(PUL3_PIN, LOW);
        PULstat3 = 0;
      }
      //curPos3 = Jf[2];
      curPos3 = curPos3 + dl3/2.0;
      if (Jf[2]-curPos3>dl3/2.0) {
        delayMicroseconds(delF);
      }
    }
  } else {
    digitalWrite(DIR3_PIN, HIGH);
    while (-Jf[2]+curPos3>dl3/2.0) {
      if (PULstat3 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(PUL3_PIN, HIGH);
        PULstat3 = 1;
      } else {
        digitalWrite(PUL3_PIN, LOW);
        PULstat3 = 0;
      }
      //curPos3 = Jf[2];
      curPos3 = curPos3 - dl3/2.0;
      if (-Jf[2]+curPos3>dl3/2.0) {
        delayMicroseconds(delF);
      }
    }
  }
  // joint #4
  if (Jf[3]-curPos4>0.0) { // positive direction of rotation
    digitalWrite(DIR4_PIN, HIGH);
    while (Jf[3]-curPos4>dl4/2.0) {
      if (PULstat4 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(PUL4_PIN, HIGH);
        PULstat4 = 1;
      } else {
        digitalWrite(PUL4_PIN, LOW);
        PULstat4 = 0;
      }
      //curPos4 = Jf[3];
      curPos4 = curPos4 + dl4/2.0;
      if (Jf[3]-curPos4>dl4/2.0) {
        delayMicroseconds(delF);
      }
    }
  } else {
    digitalWrite(DIR4_PIN, LOW);
    while (-Jf[3]+curPos4>dl4/2.0) {
      if (PULstat4 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(PUL4_PIN, HIGH);
        PULstat4 = 1;
      } else {
        digitalWrite(PUL4_PIN, LOW);
        PULstat4 = 0;
      }
      //curPos4 = Jf[3];
      curPos4 = curPos4 - dl4/2.0;
      if (-Jf[3]+curPos4>dl4/2.0) {
        delayMicroseconds(delF);
      }
    }
  }
  // joint #5
  if (Jf[4]-curPos5>0.0) { // positive direction of rotation
    digitalWrite(DIR5_PIN, HIGH);
    while (Jf[4]-curPos5>dl5/2.0) {
      if (PULstat5 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(PUL5_PIN, HIGH);
        PULstat5 = 1;
      } else {
        digitalWrite(PUL5_PIN, LOW);
        PULstat5 = 0;
      }
      //curPos5 = Jf[4];
      curPos5 = curPos5 + dl5/2.0;
      if (Jf[4]-curPos5>dl5/2.0) {
        delayMicroseconds(delF);
      }
    }
  } else {
    digitalWrite(DIR5_PIN, LOW);
    while (-Jf[4]+curPos5>dl5/2.0) {
      if (PULstat5 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(PUL5_PIN, HIGH);
        PULstat5 = 1;
      } else {
        digitalWrite(PUL5_PIN, LOW);
        PULstat5 = 0;
      }
      //curPos5 = Jf[4];
      curPos5 = curPos5 - dl5/2.0;
      if (-Jf[4]+curPos5>dl5/2.0) {
        delayMicroseconds(delF);
      }
    }
  }
  // joint #6
  if (Jf[5]-curPos6>0.0) { // positive direction of rotation
    digitalWrite(DIR6_PIN, HIGH);
    while (Jf[5]-curPos6>dl6/2.0) {
      if (PULstat6 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(PUL6_PIN, HIGH);
        PULstat6 = 1;
      } else {
        digitalWrite(PUL6_PIN, LOW);
        PULstat6 = 0;
      }
      //curPos6 = Jf[5];
      curPos6 = curPos6 + dl6/2.0;
      if (Jf[5]-curPos6>dl6/2.0) {
        delayMicroseconds(delF);
      }
    }
  } else {
    digitalWrite(DIR6_PIN, LOW);
    while (-Jf[5]+curPos6>dl6/2.0) {
      if (PULstat6 == 0) {
        digitalWrite(PUL6_PIN, HIGH);
        PULstat6 = 1;
      } else {
        digitalWrite(PUL6_PIN, LOW);
        PULstat6 = 0;
      }
      //curPos6 = Jf[5];
      curPos6 = curPos6 - dl6/2.0;
      if (-Jf[5]+curPos6>dl6/2.0) {
        delayMicroseconds(delF);
      }
    }
  }
}

void InverseK(float* Xik, float* Jik) {
  // inverse kinematics
  // input: Xik - pos value for the calculation of the inverse kinematics
  // output: Jfk - joints value for the calculation of the inversed kinematics
  
  // from deg to rad
  // Xik(4:6)=Xik(4:6)*pi/180;
  Xik[3]=Xik[3]*PI/180.0;
  Xik[4]=Xik[4]*PI/180.0;
  Xik[5]=Xik[5]*PI/180.0;
  
  // Denavit-Hartenberg matrix
  float theta[6]={0.0, 90.0, -90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}; // theta=[0; -90+0; 0; 0; 0; 0];
  float alfa[6]={90.0, 0.0, -90.0, 90.0, -90.0, 0.0}; // alfa=[-90; 0; -90; 90; -90; 0];
  float r[6]={r1, r2, r3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}; // r=[47; 110; 26; 0; 0; 0];
  float d[6]={d1, 0.0, d3, d4, 0.0, d6}; // d=[133; 0; 7; 117.5; 0; 28];
  // from deg to rad
  MatrixScale(theta, 6, 1, PI/180.0); // theta=theta*pi/180;
  MatrixScale(alfa, 6, 1, PI/180.0); // alfa=alfa*pi/180;
  
  // work frame
  float Xwf[6]={0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}; // Xwf=[0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0];
  
  // tool frame
  float Xtf[6]={0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}; // Xtf=[0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0];
  
  // work frame transformation matrix
  float Twf[16];
  pos2tran(Xwf, Twf); // Twf=pos2tran(Xwf);
  
  // tool frame transformation matrix
  float Ttf[16];
  pos2tran(Xtf, Ttf); // Ttf=pos2tran(Xtf);
  
  // total transformation matrix
  float Twt[16];
  pos2tran(Xik, Twt); // Twt=pos2tran(Xik);
  
  // find T06
  float inTwf[16], inTtf[16], Tw6[16], T06[16];
  invtran(Twf, inTwf); // inTwf=invtran(Twf);
  invtran(Ttf, inTtf); // inTtf=invtran(Ttf);
  MatrixMultiply(Twt, inTtf, 4, 4, 4, Tw6); // Tw6=Twt*inTtf;
  MatrixMultiply(inTwf, Tw6, 4, 4, 4, T06); // T06=inTwf*Tw6;
  
  // positon of the spherical wrist
  float Xsw[3];
  // Xsw=T06(1:3,4)-d(6)*T06(1:3,3);
  Xsw[0]=T06[0*4 + 3]-d[5]*T06[0*4 + 2];
  Xsw[1]=T06[1*4 + 3]-d[5]*T06[1*4 + 2];
  Xsw[2]=T06[2*4 + 3]-d[5]*T06[2*4 + 2];
  
  // joints variable
  // Jik=zeros(6,1);
  // first joint
  Jik[0]=atan2(Xsw[1],Xsw[0])-atan2(d[2],sqrt(Xsw[0]*Xsw[0]+Xsw[1]*Xsw[1]-d[2]*d[2])); // Jik(1)=atan2(Xsw(2),Xsw(1))-atan2(d(3),sqrt(Xsw(1)^2+Xsw(2)^2-d(3)^2));
  // second joint
  Jik[1]=PI/2.0
  -acos((r[1]*r[1]+(Xsw[2]-d[0])*(Xsw[2]-d[0])+(sqrt(Xsw[0]*Xsw[0]+Xsw[1]*Xsw[1]-d[2]*d[2])-r[0])*(sqrt(Xsw[0]*Xsw[0]+Xsw[1]*Xsw[1]-d[2]*d[2])-r[0])-(r[2]*r[2]+d[3]*d[3]))/(2.0*r[1]*sqrt((Xsw[2]-d[0])*(Xsw[2]-d[0])+(sqrt(Xsw[0]*Xsw[0]+Xsw[1]*Xsw[1]-d[2]*d[2])-r[0])*(sqrt(Xsw[0]*Xsw[0]+Xsw[1]*Xsw[1]-d[2]*d[2])-r[0]))))
  -atan((Xsw[2]-d[0])/(sqrt(Xsw[0]*Xsw[0]+Xsw[1]*Xsw[1]-d[2]*d[2])-r[0])); // Jik(2)=pi/2-acos((r(2)^2+(Xsw(3)-d(1))^2+(sqrt(Xsw(1)^2+Xsw(2)^2-d(3)^2)-r(1))^2-(r(3)^2+d(4)^2))/(2*r(2)*sqrt((Xsw(3)-d(1))^2+(sqrt(Xsw(1)^2+Xsw(2)^2-d(3)^2)-r(1))^2)))-atan((Xsw(3)-d(1))/(sqrt(Xsw(1)^2+Xsw(2)^2-d(3)^2)-r(1)));
  // third joint
  Jik[2]=PI
  -acos((r[1]*r[1]+r[2]*r[2]+d[3]*d[3]-(Xsw[2]-d[0])*(Xsw[2]-d[0])-(sqrt(Xsw[0]*Xsw[0]+Xsw[1]*Xsw[1]-d[2]*d[2])-r[0])*(sqrt(Xsw[0]*Xsw[0]+Xsw[1]*Xsw[1]-d[2]*d[2])-r[0]))/(2*r[1]*sqrt(r[2]*r[2]+d[3]*d[3])))
  -atan(d[3]/r[2]); // Jik(3)=pi-acos((r(2)^2+r(3)^2+d(4)^2-(Xsw(3)-d(1))^2-(sqrt(Xsw(1)^2+Xsw(2)^2-d(3)^2)-r(1))^2)/(2*r(2)*sqrt(r(3)^2+d(4)^2)))-atan(d(4)/r(3));
  // last three joints
  float T01[16], T12[16], T23[16], T02[16], T03[16], inT03[16], T36[16];
  DH1line(theta[0]+Jik[0], alfa[0], r[0], d[0], T01); // T01=DH1line(theta(1)+Jik(1),alfa(1),r(1),d(1));
  DH1line(theta[1]+Jik[1], alfa[1], r[1], d[1], T12); // T12=DH1line(theta(2)+Jik(2),alfa(2),r(2),d(2));
  DH1line(theta[2]+Jik[2], alfa[2], r[2], d[2], T23); // T23=DH1line(theta(3)+Jik(3),alfa(3),r(3),d(3));
  MatrixMultiply(T01, T12, 4, 4, 4, T02); // T02=T01*T12;
  MatrixMultiply(T02, T23, 4, 4, 4, T03); // T03=T02*T23;
  invtran(T03, inT03); // inT03=invtran(T03);
  MatrixMultiply(inT03, T06, 4, 4, 4, T36); // T36=inT03*T06;
  // forth joint
  Jik[3]=atan2(-T36[1*4+2], -T36[0*4+2]); // Jik(4)=atan2(-T36(2,3),-T36(1,3));
  // fifth joint
  Jik[4]=atan2(sqrt(T36[0*4+2]*T36[0*4+2]+T36[1*4+2]*T36[1*4+2]), T36[2*4+2]); // Jik(5)=atan2(sqrt(T36(1,3)^2+T36(2,3)^2),T36(3,3));
  // sixth joints
  Jik[5]=atan2(-T36[2*4+1], T36[2*4+0]); // Jik(6)=atan2(-T36(3,2),T36(3,1));
  // rad to deg
  MatrixScale(Jik, 6, 1, 180.0/PI); // Jik=Jik/pi*180;
}

void ForwardK(float* Jfk, float* Xfk)
{
  // forward kinematics
  // input: Jfk - joints value for the calculation of the forward kinematics
  // output: Xfk - pos value for the calculation of the forward kinematics
  
  // Denavit-Hartenberg matrix
  float theTemp[6]={0.0, 90.0, -90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
  float theta[6];
  MatrixAdd(theTemp, Jfk, 6, 1, theta); // theta=[Jfk(1); -90+Jfk(2); Jfk(3); Jfk(4); Jfk(5); Jfk(6)];
  float alfa[6]={90.0, 0.0, -90.0, 90.0, -90.0, 0.0}; // alfa=[-90; 0; -90; 90; -90; 0];
  float r[6]={r1, r2, r3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}; // r=[47; 110; 26; 0; 0; 0];
  float d[6]={d1, 0.0, d3, d4, 0.0, d6}; // d=[133; 0; 7; 117.5; 0; 28];
  // from deg to rad
  MatrixScale(theta, 6, 1, PI/180.0); // theta=theta*pi/180;
  MatrixScale(alfa, 6, 1, PI/180.0); // alfa=alfa*pi/180;
  
  // work frame
  float Xwf[6]={0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}; // Xwf=[0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0];
  
  // tool frame
  float Xtf[6]={0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}; // Xtf=[0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0];
  
  // work frame transformation matrix
  float Twf[16];
  pos2tran(Xwf, Twf); // Twf=pos2tran(Xwf);
  
  // tool frame transformation matrix
  float Ttf[16];
  pos2tran(Xtf, Ttf); // Ttf=pos2tran(Xtf);
  
  // DH homogeneous transformation matrix
  float T01[16], T12[16], T23[16], T34[16], T45[16], T56[16];
  DH1line(theta[0], alfa[0], r[0], d[0], T01); // T01=DH1line(theta(1),alfa(1),r(1),d(1));
  DH1line(theta[1], alfa[1], r[1], d[1], T12); // T12=DH1line(theta(2),alfa(2),r(2),d(2));
  DH1line(theta[2], alfa[2], r[2], d[2], T23); // T23=DH1line(theta(3),alfa(3),r(3),d(3));
  DH1line(theta[3], alfa[3], r[3], d[3], T34); // T34=DH1line(theta(4),alfa(4),r(4),d(4));
  DH1line(theta[4], alfa[4], r[4], d[4], T45); // T45=DH1line(theta(5),alfa(5),r(5),d(5));
  DH1line(theta[5], alfa[5], r[5], d[5], T56); // T56=DH1line(theta(6),alfa(6),r(6),d(6));

  float Tw1[16], Tw2[16], Tw3[16], Tw4[16], Tw5[16], Tw6[16], Twt[16];
  MatrixMultiply(Twf, T01, 4, 4, 4, Tw1); // Tw1=Twf*T01;
  MatrixMultiply(Tw1, T12, 4, 4, 4, Tw2); // Tw2=Tw1*T12;
  MatrixMultiply(Tw2, T23, 4, 4, 4, Tw3); // Tw3=Tw2*T23;
  MatrixMultiply(Tw3, T34, 4, 4, 4, Tw4); // Tw4=Tw3*T34;
  MatrixMultiply(Tw4, T45, 4, 4, 4, Tw5); // Tw5=Tw4*T45;
  MatrixMultiply(Tw5, T56, 4, 4, 4, Tw6); // Tw6=Tw5*T56;
  MatrixMultiply(Tw6, Ttf, 4, 4, 4, Twt); // Twt=Tw6*Ttf;
  
  // calculate pos from transformation matrix
  tran2pos(Twt, Xfk); // Xfk=tran2pos(Twt);
  // Xfk(4:6)=Xfk(4:6)/pi*180;
  Xfk[3]=Xfk[3]/PI*180.0;
  Xfk[4]=Xfk[4]/PI*180.0;
  Xfk[5]=Xfk[5]/PI*180.0;
}

void invtran(float* Titi, float* Titf)
{
  // finding the inverse of the homogeneous transformation matrix
  // first row
  Titf[0*4 + 0] = Titi[0*4 + 0];
  Titf[0*4 + 1] = Titi[1*4 + 0];
  Titf[0*4 + 2] = Titi[2*4 + 0];
  Titf[0*4 + 3] = -Titi[0*4 + 0]*Titi[0*4 + 3]-Titi[1*4 + 0]*Titi[1*4 + 3]-Titi[2*4 + 0]*Titi[2*4 + 3];
  // second row
  Titf[1*4 + 0] = Titi[0*4 + 1];
  Titf[1*4 + 1] = Titi[1*4 + 1];
  Titf[1*4 + 2] = Titi[2*4 + 1];
  Titf[1*4 + 3] = -Titi[0*4 + 1]*Titi[0*4 + 3]-Titi[1*4 + 1]*Titi[1*4 + 3]-Titi[2*4 + 1]*Titi[2*4 + 3];
  // third row
  Titf[2*4 + 0] = Titi[0*4 + 2];
  Titf[2*4 + 1] = Titi[1*4 + 2];
  Titf[2*4 + 2] = Titi[2*4 + 2];
  Titf[2*4 + 3] = -Titi[0*4 + 2]*Titi[0*4 + 3]-Titi[1*4 + 2]*Titi[1*4 + 3]-Titi[2*4 + 2]*Titi[2*4 + 3];
  // forth row
  Titf[3*4 + 0] = 0.0;
  Titf[3*4 + 1] = 0.0;
  Titf[3*4 + 2] = 0.0;
  Titf[3*4 + 3] = 1.0;
}

void tran2pos(float* Ttp, float* Xtp)
{
  // pos from homogeneous transformation matrix
  Xtp[0] = Ttp[0*4 + 3];
  Xtp[1] = Ttp[1*4 + 3];
  Xtp[2] = Ttp[2*4 + 3];
  Xtp[4] = atan2(sqrt(Ttp[2*4 + 0]*Ttp[2*4 + 0] + Ttp[2*4 + 1]*Ttp[2*4 + 1]),Ttp[2*4 + 2]);
  Xtp[3] = atan2(Ttp[1*4 + 2]/sin(Xtp[4]),Ttp[0*4 + 2]/sin(Xtp[4]));
  Xtp[5] = atan2(Ttp[2*4 + 1]/sin(Xtp[4]),-Ttp[2*4 + 0]/sin(Xtp[4]));
}

void pos2tran(float* Xpt, float* Tpt)
{
  // pos to homogeneous transformation matrix
  // first row
  Tpt[0*4 + 0] = cos(Xpt[3])*cos(Xpt[4])*cos(Xpt[5])-sin(Xpt[3])*sin(Xpt[5]);
  Tpt[0*4 + 1] = -cos(Xpt[3])*cos(Xpt[4])*sin(Xpt[5])-sin(Xpt[3])*cos(Xpt[5]);
  Tpt[0*4 + 2] = cos(Xpt[3])*sin(Xpt[4]);
  Tpt[0*4 + 3] = Xpt[0];
  // second row
  Tpt[1*4 + 0] = sin(Xpt[3])*cos(Xpt[4])*cos(Xpt[5])+cos(Xpt[3])*sin(Xpt[5]);
  Tpt[1*4 + 1] = -sin(Xpt[3])*cos(Xpt[4])*sin(Xpt[5])+cos(Xpt[3])*cos(Xpt[5]);
  Tpt[1*4 + 2] = sin(Xpt[3])*sin(Xpt[4]);
  Tpt[1*4 + 3] = Xpt[1];
  // third row
  Tpt[2*4 + 0] = -sin(Xpt[4])*cos(Xpt[5]);
  Tpt[2*4 + 1] = sin(Xpt[4])*sin(Xpt[5]);
  Tpt[2*4 + 2] = cos(Xpt[4]);
  Tpt[2*4 + 3] = Xpt[2];
  // forth row
  Tpt[3*4 + 0] = 0.0;
  Tpt[3*4 + 1] = 0.0;
  Tpt[3*4 + 2] = 0.0;
  Tpt[3*4 + 3] = 1.0;
}

void DH1line(float thetadh, float alfadh, float rdh, float ddh, float* Tdh)
{
  // creats Denavit-Hartenberg homogeneous transformation matrix
  // first row
  Tdh[0*4 + 0] = cos(thetadh);
  Tdh[0*4 + 1] = -sin(thetadh)*cos(alfadh);
  Tdh[0*4 + 2] = sin(thetadh)*sin(alfadh);
  Tdh[0*4 + 3] = rdh*cos(thetadh);
  // second row
  Tdh[1*4 + 0] = sin(thetadh);
  Tdh[1*4 + 1] = cos(thetadh)*cos(alfadh);
  Tdh[1*4 + 2] = -cos(thetadh)*sin(alfadh);
  Tdh[1*4 + 3] = rdh*sin(thetadh);
  // third row
  Tdh[2*4 + 0] = 0.0;
  Tdh[2*4 + 1] = sin(alfadh);
  Tdh[2*4 + 2] = cos(alfadh);
  Tdh[2*4 + 3] = ddh;
  // forth row
  Tdh[3*4 + 0] = 0.0;
  Tdh[3*4 + 1] = 0.0;
  Tdh[3*4 + 2] = 0.0;
  Tdh[3*4 + 3] = 1.0;
}

void MatrixPrint(float* A, int m, int n, String label)
{
  // A = input matrix (m x n)
  int i, j;
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(label);
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
      Serial.print(A[n * i + j]);
      Serial.print("\t");
    }
    Serial.println();
  }
}

void MatrixCopy(float* A, int n, int m, float* B)
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
      B[n * i + j] = A[n * i + j];
    }
}

//Matrix Multiplication Routine
// C = A*B
void MatrixMultiply(float* A, float* B, int m, int p, int n, float* C)
{
  // A = input matrix (m x p)
  // B = input matrix (p x n)
  // m = number of rows in A
  // p = number of columns in A = number of rows in B
  // n = number of columns in B
  // C = output matrix = A*B (m x n)
  int i, j, k;
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
      C[n * i + j] = 0;
      for (k = 0; k < p; k++)
        C[n * i + j] = C[n * i + j] + A[p * i + k] * B[n * k + j];
    }
}


//Matrix Addition Routine
void MatrixAdd(float* A, float* B, int m, int n, float* C)
{
  // A = input matrix (m x n)
  // B = input matrix (m x n)
  // m = number of rows in A = number of rows in B
  // n = number of columns in A = number of columns in B
  // C = output matrix = A+B (m x n)
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
      C[n * i + j] = A[n * i + j] + B[n * i + j];
}


//Matrix Subtraction Routine
void MatrixSubtract(float* A, float* B, int m, int n, float* C)
{
  // A = input matrix (m x n)
  // B = input matrix (m x n)
  // m = number of rows in A = number of rows in B
  // n = number of columns in A = number of columns in B
  // C = output matrix = A-B (m x n)
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
      C[n * i + j] = A[n * i + j] - B[n * i + j];
}


//Matrix Transpose Routine
void MatrixTranspose(float* A, int m, int n, float* C)
{
  // A = input matrix (m x n)
  // m = number of rows in A
  // n = number of columns in A
  // C = output matrix = the transpose of A (n x m)
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
      C[m * j + i] = A[n * i + j];
}

void MatrixScale(float* A, int m, int n, float k)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
      A[n * i + j] = A[n * i + j] * k;
}
```

Comment: @jsotola so more people will see this xD

Comment: @EBMare what jsotola mean is, if u wanna ask question, explain what modification have u done, what result u expect from modification and what the actual result of experiment. U cannot expect an answer if u only state "still does not work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i would address one of your problem :

- Weird result

One thing you need to understand while working with serial manipulator control inverse kinematic is concept of multi solution. With understanding that 6 dof serial manipulator usually consist of anthromorphic arm (basic 2 dof planar robot) and spherical wrist, therefore a multi solution possibly exist for one point.

[image: Multi solution of serial manipulator inverse kinematic]

Fig 1. Solution A and solution B for point x,y

Simple testing give result that configuration :

q = [0 0 90 0 90 0]

**Didn't give position 224, 0, 280 (x,y,z)**

But it give
HTM :

```
    -1         0         0        -1
     0         1         0         0
     0         0        -1        57
     0         0         0         1
```

Read : -1, 0, 57 (x,y,z)

while this configuration would give u the position u want :

q = [ 0 0 0 -180 180 -180]

q = [0  -84.3114   19.6625 0   65.1509 0]

Additional note :

for -224 in x axis, maybe u wanna check if ur code have additional minus symbol or anything that accidentally make the value of x is -1. Testing with another configuration may help.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try this out.

Comment: Do you know any free software i could use? Instead of using this arduino sketch.

Comment: @EBMare the testing is done in matlab using rtb in here https://petercorke.com/toolboxes/robotics-toolbox/, but the last news he already develop it in python So u can check it out there

Comment: I tried your configuration and it does not work.
forward:
422.80
0.00
525.01
180.00
0.50
180.00
But even when I calculate the coordiantes and angles with the forward kinematics and then type them into the inverse kinematic function the resulting angles are still wrong

Comment: @EBMare hm, what forward kinematic result of home position [0 0 0 0 0 0]?

Comment: forward:
-0.00
-0.00
854.00
nan
0.00
nan

Comment: The inverse kinematics for the home (0.0, 0.0, 854.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 position: 0.00
0.00
-90.00
-0.00
90.00
-0.00

Comment: Yes i just realize variable theta is not the value of joint angle, but the offset. Thats why it bring confusion.

Comment: Do u input q = [ 0 0 0 -180 180 -180] and q = [0 -84.3114 19.6625 0 65.1509 0] the same way? if it same way, the it should give the same result then

Comment: Should I input q = [ 0 0 0 -180 180 -180] into the inverse kinematics and this q = [0 -84.3114 19.6625 0 65.1509 0] into the forward?

Comment: put both of it in forward kinematic.. one at a time obviously

Comment: The result for q = [ 0 0 0 -180 180 -180]:forward:
-0.00
-0.00
504.00
-135.00
180.00
-135.00
And the result for q = [0 -84.3114 19.6625 0 65.1509 0]:
forward:
422.80
0.00
525.01
180.00
0.50
180.00